# Show E is an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a reflexive and transitive relation on a set $X$.  Define a new relation $E$ on $S$ by, $$xEy \iff  xRy \space and \space yRx$$ for $x,y \in X.$  Show that $E$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.

$\underline{My \space attempt:}$  We must show that $E$ is reflexive, transitive, and symmetric.  For each one of these conditions we must show both directions because of the if and only if condition.

To show $E$ is reflexive for the forward direction we must show $xRy \space and \space yRx$.  Setting $y=x$ seems to do the job since $R$ is reflexive.  Now for the backward direction it is pretty much the same idea.
Now I am stuck for the others, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, note that, in the definition, the "if and only if" defines it, and x and y are both just dummy variables. We could just as easily use z & w. Now then:

To prove reflexivity, you *must* prove that xRx for ALL x - just in case that wasn't clear before.

To prove symmetry, you must assume xEy (for arbitrary x & y) and deduce yEx, because symmetry means that xEy iff yEx. Therefore, xEy implies xRy and yRx by definition. Switch those around, and you get yRx and xRy, which satisfies the definition of yEx; therefore E is symmetric.

Transitivity means that for x, y and z, xEy and yEz together imply xEz. Assume the hypotheses and prove the conclusion. Since xEy, that means xRy and yRx. Since yEz, that means yRz and zRy.

Now, because xRy and yRz and R is transitive, we have xRz. And because yRx and zRy and R is transitive, we have zRx. So now we have both xRz and zRx, which satisfies the definition of xEz. So, E is transitive. That proves it.